# Missing Private key error when creating Encrypted Data Bag with Knife

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to create an encrypted Data bag to store a Mysql password and followed the instructions [here](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Encrypted+Data+Bags) to run this command:

```
knife data bag create --secret-file /tmp/my_data_bag_key passwords mysql
```

This returns an error:

> Error: "Your private key could not be loaded from
>   /Users/ClientName/.chef/ClientName.pem"
>   Check your configuration file and ensure that your private key is readable

Now there is no .pem file at that location.But do I really need one? For Chef solo?
If I do, then how do I create this file?

Answer (score 2):

This command works by connecting to a chef server.  If you don't have a key, this will fail.  However, this knife plugin seems to do what you are looking for:

https://github.com/cparedes/knife-file

N.B., I have not used this plugin, but it looks right to me

Answer (score 2):

The gist of it is that the Opscode links in the original post that point to Encrypted Data Bag creation instructions will not work for Chef-solo. The way to make Encrypted Data Bags work with Chef-solo is [described here](http://ed.victavision.co.uk/blog/post/4-8-2012-chef-solo-encrypted-data-bags).

Comment: Hey udit, the link does not load any content. Do you know if there is another link?